# Ip location finder

Tags: php, location, ip

I want to find the location (country, city,..) of my site visitor by their IP.
I'm coding php.
who can help me?
something like this:

```
   $url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=/*userapikey*/
    ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."&format=json"));
    $country=$url->countryName;  // user country
    $city=$url->cityName;       // city
    $region=$url->regionName;   // regoin
    $latitude=$url->latitude;    //lat and lon
    $longitude=$url->longitude;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a `&` missing in the URL:

```
$url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=/*userapikey*/&ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."&format=json"));
```

Probably, you should encode the IP:

```
$url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=/*userapikey*/&ip=".urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."&format=json"));
```

Then you can do this to get information about the result:

```
var_dump($url);
```

If you have another problem, please write it to the question.

Comment: What is the result?! Please read the FAQs to Stack Overflow. Your question and this comment is very unspecific.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [freegeoip.net](https://freegeoip.net). It's a webservice that gives you exactly the data you need for a specific IP.

E.g.:

```
https://freegeoip.net/json/1.2.3.4
```

will give you this JSON data:

```
{
    ip: "1.2.3.4",
    country_code: "US",
    country_name: "USA",
    region_code: "WA",
    region_name: "Washington",
    city: "Mukilteo",
    zip_code: "98275",
    time_zone: "America/Los_Angeles",
    latitude: 47.945,
    longitude: -122.305,
    metro_code: 819
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://freegeoip.net/.  They offer a free API for up to 10,000 searches per hour.

---

Example:

```
$res         = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://freegeoip.net/json/109.80.75.20"));
$countryCode = $res->country_code;
$country     = $res->country_name;
```